# Django-sphinx result filtering using attributes?

Tags: django, search, filter, sphinx, resultset

I was going through the django-sphinx [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/django-sphinx/), and it looks like it allows you to filter search results using *attributes*,

```
queryset = MyModel.search.query('query')
results1 = queryset.order_by('@weight', '@id', 'my_attribute')
results2 = queryset.filter(my_attribute=5)
results3 = queryset.filter(my_other_attribute=[5, 3,4])
results4 = queryset.exclude(my_attribute=5)[0:10]
```

From some examples, these attributes seem to be something you specify in the sphinx configuration file, rather than being actual column values in the table. The configuration file allows something like this,

```
# ForeignKey's
# Apparently sql_group_column is now replaced by sql_attr_uint
sql_group_column    = country_id
sql_group_column    = state_id
sql_group_column    = listings

# DateField's and DateTimeField's
sql_date_column     = date_added
```

But it turns out that you can only specify **Foreign Keys** as this value. As illustrated in [another example](http://www.davidcramer.net/code/django/433/setting-up-django-and-sphinx-full-text-search-django-sphinx.html),

```
Class City(models.Model):
    ...
    # Comment: The below should probly be country_id and state_id
    country_id      = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    state_id        = models.ForeignKey(State, blank=True, null=True)
    listings        = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
```

When the search result is printed, you get,

```
print results[0]._sphinx
{'id': u'5246', 'weight': 200, 'attrs': {'state_id': 3, 'country_id': 0}}
```

As you can see, in attrs - state_id and country_id - being FKs, show up. But listings doesn't.

And here lies my problem. If I want to filter my sphinx search results using an aribtrary column foo in my model - how would I do it?

Thanks!

---

Edit

In answer to Van Gale,

I'm actually using sql_attr_uint rather than sql_group_column here.. and as I mentioned in the example above.. even the example from the author of Django Sphinx (link given above) doesn't show the attribute in the _Sphinx dict if its not a FK.. (See the "As you can see" statement above). Also, I already have the SQL_Query string too.. it selects all columns in my table.. (individually, not *)

Comment: did you get a solution to this problem? I am stuck her...

Answer (score 1):

It's been almost a year since I did a project using django-sphinx, so my memory is a bit hazy on this.  But, knowing I was able to filter on normal columns, I'll just post the relevant portions of my sphinx config and maybe that will help.

**sphinx.conf:**

```
sql_query_pre       =
sql_query_post      =
sql_query           = SELECT `id`, `content_type_id`, `site_id`, `user_id`, `title`, `abstract`, `summary`, `fulltext`, `approved` FROM `basedoc`
sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM `basedoc` WHERE `id` = $id

sql_attr_uint    = content_type_id
sql_attr_uint    = site_id
sql_attr_uint    = user_id
sql_attr_uint    = approved
```

As you can see, I had a non-fk column (approved) and did filter on it in the django view.  So I'm guessing your problem is you need `sql_attr_uint` instead of `sql_group_column`, and add the `sql_query` strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but I am already using sql_attr_uint, and have all columns in my table as part of the select query.. except, I am not using the `` to mark each column name. Not sure if that alone might make a difference, but I'll try it out.

Comment: Btw - I'm still stuck with this problem. I was wondering - how did you end up doing your filtering in the view? Perhaps thats what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When I was working on the prototype project using django-sphinx there was a bug where filters wouldn't reset properly (i.e. once you used a filter it would always apply to every search after that even if you didn't want it).  It has since been fixed but, because of this bug, I obviously couldn't use filters.  I had to use the .query() method and then manually filter out the record id's myself.  I'll edit my post to show how I used filters because they did work for me other than the reset problem.

Comment: Gah, I apologize, but we migrated the source to git and only kept the most recent version of the code (it was only a prototype site that was discontinued).  So I don't have a copy anywhere of the older code that used sphinx filters... sorry :(